# How to remove a name from a list if user doesn't accept invitation

Tags: python, list

Here's what I have been asked to do:

> Create a program that will use 2 Lists to store details about guests invited to a wedding.
> Method:
> Set up two lists - one for the names of the guests and one to store whether the invitation has been accepted or not. NOTE the second array should be a list of boolean elements that are initially set to false
> You need to ask for the names of the guests and then ask if they are attending the wedding.
> Print out a list of only those who will attend.

Here is what I have done:

```
names = [""]*10
accept = [False]*10
accepted = [""]*10
counter = 10

for counter in range(0,10):
  names[counter] = str(input("What is your name?"))
  accepted[counter] = input("Are you accepting the invitation?")
  
  
  if accepted[counter] == "Yes" or accepted[counter] == "yes":
    accept[counter] = True
  else:
    names[counter] = ""

print("Here is a list of peoples names whom are attending:")
print(names)
```

And here is what my teacher said:

> Works but can you think of a better way to display the names of those attending?

Are you able to help me work this out, I think the teacher wants me to remove the name from the list however I don't know how to do this. I have tried using pop() but I just don't understand it. :(

Comment: Can you show *how* you tried to use `pop`, what you expected that to do, and what it did instead?

Comment: ```names = [""]*10
accept = [False]*10
accepted = [""]*10
counter = 10

for counter in range(0,10):
  names[counter] = str(input("What is your name?"))
  accepted[counter] = input("Are you accepting the invitation?")
  
  
  if accepted[counter] == "Yes" or accepted[counter] == "yes":
    accept[counter] = True
  else:
    pop(names[counter])

print("Here is a list of peoples names whom are attending:")
print(names)``` 

But the program just says this:

 "raceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in <module>
NameError: name 'pop' is not defined"

Comment: Please add code as an edit to the post, not a comment.

Comment: Thinking about your current implementation there are two things which could be annoying to the user (1) you are throwing away the name data of people who didn't accept. What's the point of storing a False but not recording who said it? (2) When you print the list you will have lots of empty strings dotted amongst the names. That's not nice to look at and also could create issues if someone wanted to take this list and load it into another tool. Barmar's answer solves both, but worth taking the time to think through what your teacher might have meant by 'better'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `names` list is supposed to contain all the people who were invited, you shouldn't replace a name with an empty string, because then it won't be complete.

Use a loop to print the names of just the people who are attending, using the index in the corresponding element in the `accepted` list.

There's also no need for `accepted` to be a list. Just use an ordinary variable for the current answer.

```
names = [""]*10
accept = [False]*10

for counter in range(0,10):
  names[counter] = input("What is your name?")
  accepted = input("Are you accepting the invitation?")
  
  if accepted.lower() == "yes":
      accept[counter] = True

print("Here is a list of peoples names whom are attending:")
for i, attending in enumerate(accept):
    if attending:
        print(names[i])
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range" after entering 3 names.

Comment: Sorry, `accepted[counter]` should have been `accepted`.

Answer (score 0):

`pop()` is used to remove a value from a list. If used without parameters, it will remove the last value. If given a value it will "pop it", or delete it in other words, and print the deleted value.